# Why doesn't cornerRadius work by SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I designated the `clipShape` and just `cornerRadius(20)` for the image by SwiftUI.
It did clip the image. But it did not correctly. Why?

```
  Image("sample_image")
          .resizable()
          .scaledToFit()
          .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
          .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50))
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. You also need to include the input image that produced the unexpected result, as well as a screenshot of the actual result vs the expected result.

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.cornerRadius` instead of `.clipShape`

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string:imageUrl)) { image in
    image
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        .cornerRadius(50)
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, Ori. I did changed it. But it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm... I suggest you edit your question and provide more information like
[@Dávid Pásztorsuggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4667835/d%c3%a1vid-p%c3%a1sztor) suggested. It will help me as well as others to help you :)